# Need help to retrieve data from three MySQL tables

Tags: mysql

I have three tables named "users","user_hobbies" and "hobbies". Below is the sample tables with values;
Below is the **users** table with `fields id, name and age`

```
╔════╦══════╦═════╗
║ ID ║ NAME ║ AGE ║
╠════╬══════╬═════╣
║  1 ║ abc  ║  23 ║
║  2 ║ xyz  ║  24 ║
║  3 ║ pqr  ║  21 ║
╚════╩══════╩═════╝
```

and below is **user_hobbies** table with fields id, user_id and hobby_id

```
╔════╦═════════╦══════════╗
║ ID ║ USER_ID ║ HOBBY_ID ║
╠════╬═════════╬══════════╣
║  1 ║       1 ║        1 ║
║  2 ║       1 ║        2 ║
║  3 ║       1 ║        3 ║
║  4 ║       2 ║        4 ║
║  5 ║       2 ║        3 ║
║  6 ║       2 ║        5 ║
║  7 ║       3 ║        2 ║
║  8 ║       4 ║        6 ║
╚════╩═════════╩══════════╝
```

. Below is the **hobbies** table with fields id and desc

```
╔════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║   DESC    ║
╠════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ music     ║
║  2 ║ chatting  ║
║  3 ║ cricket   ║
║  4 ║ badminton ║
║  5 ║ chess     ║
║  6 ║ cooking   ║
╚════╩═══════════╝
```

. The actual requirement is that i need a query to retrieve name, age, hobby_id and desc (see an example below)

```
╔══════╦═════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ NAME ║ AGE ║ HOBBYID  ║        DESC             ║
╠══════╬═════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ abc  ║  23 ║ 1,2,3    ║ music,chatting,cricket  ║
║ pqr  ║  21 ║ 2        ║ chatting                ║
║ xyz  ║  24 ║ 4,3,5    ║ badminton,cricket,chess ║
╚══════╩═════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to join the tables first and use an aggregate function called `GROUP_CONCAT()`.

```
SELECT  a.Name,
        a.Age,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.ID) hobbyIDs,
        GROUP_CONCAT(c.desc) descList
FROM    users a
        INNER JOIN user_hobbies b
            ON a.ID = b.user_ID
        INNER JOIN hobbies c
            ON b.hobby_ID = c.ID
GROUP   BY a.Name, a.Age
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3172/3)
- [MySQL GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

OUTPUT

```
╔══════╦═════╦══════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║ NAME ║ AGE ║ HOBBYIDS ║        DESCLIST         ║
╠══════╬═════╬══════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ abc  ║  23 ║ 1,2,3    ║ music,chatting,cricket  ║
║ pqr  ║  21 ║ 2        ║ chatting                ║
║ xyz  ║  24 ║ 4,3,5    ║ badminton,cricket,chess ║
╚══════╩═════╩══════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```